# Django two separate forms under single page / url

Tags: django, forms

I have two forms which I want to display and use on index page of the website.

Index page is a HomeView which in it's context contains two forms - ContactForm and SubscribtionForm.

My goal is to use these two forms on single page. So far it is impossible because each time validation fails it redirects me to view which is responsible for form validation.

Fragment of index page html code:

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact form-horizontal" action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="post" novalidate>

<form id="newsletter-form" class="newsletter_form" action="{% url 'subscribe' %}" method="post" novalidate>
```

How do I do it in django that when I submit it will use other views to validate and save the data but responses will be displayed on Index page? Should I use javascript/ajax calls to solve this issue? Or there is another way?

Edit:

```
class SubscriberFormView(FormView):
    form_class = SubscriberForm
    template_name = 'home/subscriber_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())


class ContactFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = "home/contact_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save()
        instance.send_confirmation()
        instance.send_notification()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Alternative solution with prefixes:

```
class HomeView(FormMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    form_class_sub = SubscriberForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('home')

    def get_forms(self):
        contact_kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs().copy()
        contact_kwargs['prefix'] = 'contact'
        sub_kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs().copy()
        sub_kwargs['prefix'] = 'sub'
        return {
            'contact_form': self.form_class(**contact_kwargs),
            'subscription_form': self.form_class_sub(**sub_kwargs),
        }

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        forms = self.get_forms()
        if 'contact-submit' in request.POST:
            form = forms['contact_form']
            form_name = 'contact_form'
        elif 'newsletter-submit' in request.POST:
            form = forms['subscription_form']
            form_name = 'subscription_form'
        else:
            raise Http404

        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, form_name)

    def form_invalid(self, form, form_name):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'contact_form' not in data:
            data['contact_form'] = self.get_forms()['contact_form']
        if 'subscription_form' not in data:
            data['subscription_form'] = self.get_forms()['subscription_form']
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Function based view (index):

```
def index(request):
    contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST or None, prefix='contact')
    subscription_form = SubscriberForm(request.POST or None, prefix='sub')

    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'contact-submit' in request.POST:
            form = contact_form
        elif 'sub-submit' in request.POST:
            form = subscription_form
        else:
            raise Http404

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return TemplateResponse(request, template="index.html", context={
        'contact_form': contact_form,
        'subscription_form': subscription_form,
    })
```

Final version:

```
def index(request):
    contact_form = ContactForm(None, prefix='contact')
    subscription_form = SubscriberForm(None, prefix='sub')

    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'contact-submit' in request.POST:
            contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST, prefix='contact')
            if contact_form.is_valid():
                contact_form.save()
        elif 'sub-submit' in request.POST:
            subscription_form = SubscriberForm(request.POST, prefix='sub')
            if contact_form.is_valid():
                contact_form.save()
        else:
            raise Http404

    return TemplateResponse(request, template="index.html", context={
        'contact_form': contact_form,
        'subscription_form': subscription_form,
    })
```

Comment: Can you please add code of the views that handle your contact and subscribe forms?

Comment: @Nick added to main post

Answer (score 0):

You should not use different view do validate data. The forms should be validated in the same view where they've been rendered.

To be able to use multiple forms in one view, simply use form prefix:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms

Comment: I did so but when I submit a form it validates both of them - I have attached new code to initial post

Comment: Oh you haven't mentioned using CBV, `FormMixin` is not really intended to be used with multiple forms. I would just go back to functional view in this case. As you see from the codebase, you don't really gain to much by sticking to CBV.

Comment: I've added a function based view to main post. When I submit the form it still validates both of them.

Comment: I've added final version in my first post. Please take a look at it :)

Comment: Just so I get this - you want to process both forms at the same time by clicking any of the submit button..?

Comment: I don't want to process both forms when I click submit - by clicking submit I want to process just one form.